# How open battery usage by click in android

Tags: android, onclick, android-button, battery

I want open the battery usage setting by click a button. The code is this:

```
Button btnusage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.batteryusage);
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        openOptionsBatt();
    }
});
```

And the method:

```
public openOptionsBatt(View v) {
    Intent intentBatteryUsage = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_POWER_USAGE_SUMMARY);        
    startActivity(intentBatteryUsage);
}
```

The application crash onCreate.. Why?

Comment: Post your entire code. The provided snippets don't add up

Comment: When come back home i'll post it..but i think is correct the method right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
Button btnusage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.batteryusage);
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        openOptionsBatt();
    }
});
```

to

```
Button btnusage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.batteryusage);
btnusage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        openOptionsBatt();
    }
});
```

Note that in the second code snippet you're using `btnusage`, not `Button`. You want the `OnClickListener` to attach to your instance of `Button` not the class `Button` itself.

Also, you're calling `openOptionsBatt();` with passes 0 arguments, when your method `public openOptionsBatt(View v)` requires 1. I would change `public openOptionsBatt(View v)` to take 0 arguments. You're also missing the keyword `void` in your method signature.

`public void openOptionsBatt()`

Comment: If i write `public openOptionsBatt()` i get errore in `openOptionsBatt`. It say "expected MainActivity".

Comment: But if i write `public void openOptionsBatt()` it doesn't get me errors but the application crash.

Comment: Did you make the first change I suggested also? Maybe btnusage is null. I would recommend getting a better understanding of how Java works before attempting to write your first app.

Comment: What you mean when you say that si null?i've declare it everywhere i think.. Yes i made the changes.. I have a fatal exception main error

Answer (score 0):

It seems that:

```
public openOptionsBatt(View v) { ... }
```

takes a View "v" but when you use the method itself you forget to set the view:

```
openOptionsBatt();
```

Based on the changes suggested previously as well as this, try changing your code to the following:

```
Button btnusage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.batteryusage);
btnusage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        openOptionsBatt(v);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.